# Remove a block from a config file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a config file that has the following block layout:

```
{
  test,
  gracePeriodMinutes: "",
  silences: [
  {
"condition": "",
"silenceUntil": "XXXXXXXX",
"silenceComment": ""
 }
]
}
```

and the file has multiple blocks.

I want to find out how to remove the lines AFTER "silences: [" and BEFORE "]". I can easily remove the portion include "silences: [" and "]" with sed, but could not figure out how to keep them and remove everything in between.

Comment: Yes, it is a JSON file.

Comment: It's not JSON if the keys aren't quoted.

Comment: `out how to keep them and remove everything in between.` https://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/sed-delete-the-lines-lying-in-between-two-patterns/ `I can easily remove the portion include` - please post the code that does that.

Comment: If it's a JSON, use [tag:jq]

Comment: I can use this: sed '/silences\:\ \[/,/\]/d' file_name to remove all the blocks starting with "silences: [" and ends with "]". But I want to keep them in the file, just remove everything between them...

Answer (score 2):

When logic gets more complex, it is often easier to use awk instead of sed.  Try:

```
$ awk '/\]/{f=0}; f==0{print}; /silences: \[/{f=1}' file
{
  test,
  gracePeriodMinutes: "",
  silences: [
]
}
```

#### How it works:

The awk script uses one variable `f`.  In awk, variables default to zero or empty.

- `/\]/{f=0}`

  This tells awk to set `f` to zero whenever we reach a line that contains `]`.
- `f==0{print}`

  This tells awk to print the line if `f` is zero.
- `/silences: \[/{f=1}`

  If the current line includes `silences: [`, this tells awk to set `f` to one.

Lastly awk programmers often pride themselves on conciseness.  In this case, since `{print}` is the default action, we don't need to include it:

```
awk '/\]/{f=0}; f==0; /silences: \[/{f=1}'
```

Or, since, under awk rules, zero is false, we could write `f==0` as not-`f` or `!f` and this makes the code even shorter (hat tip: [Jotne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341847/jotne)):

```
awk '/\]/{f=0}; !f; /silences: \[/{f=1}' file
```

And, since in this case there is no ambiguity, we can omit first of the two semicolons, saving another character:

```
awk '/\]/{f=0} !f; /silences: \[/{f=1}' file
```

Comment: @Jotne Very true.  Thanks.  Answer updated with `!f`.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured that I could use the below sed:

```
sed '/silences\:\ \[/,/\]/{//!s/.*//;}' file | sed '/^$/d'
```

The first part replaces every lines between "silences: [" and "]" with a blank line. The second part deletes the blank lines.

Comment: Very good but there is no need to start two sed processes.  Try instead `sed '/silences\:\ \[/,/\]/{//!s/.*//;}; /^$/d' file` or, even simpler, try `sed '/silences\:\ \[/,/\]/{//!d}' file`