# Replacing lines with carriage return with Sed

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I have the following file that I would like to alter :

```
authorize {
        update request {
                Monthly-Usage = "%{sql:SELECT COALESCE((SUM(`acctoutputoctets`)), 0) FROM radacct WHERE `username`='%{User-Name}' AND Month(acctupdatetime)=(Month(NOW())) AND Year(acctupdatetime)=Year(NOW())}"
        }

    filter_username
    etc


}
```

so that it becomes like this (update request { ... } is removed)

```
authorize {

    filter_username
    etc
}
```

I have looked up some examples and came up with this, but it doesn't work:

```
sed -i 'N; s/update request {\nMonthly-Usage = "%{sql:SELECT COALESCE((SUM(`acctoutputoctets`)), 0) FROM radacct WHERE `username`='"'"'%{User-Name}'"'"' AND Month(acctupdatetime)=(Month(NOW())) AND Year(acctupdatetime)=Year(NOW())}"\n}//g' /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
```

Comment: are the multiple occurrences of `authorize` or `update request` in a file where you would need to leave the others untouched? Why not just recreate a new file with the blank template as you show? Good luck.

Comment: this works: `awk '/^}/{f=0} !f; /authorize {/{f=1}' <file>`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58243951/1251660 for more details.

Comment: @shellter Yes there are multiple `update request` but only one `authorize {`. Thanks

Comment: @slayedbylucifer sadly that won't work. There are other stuff in `authorize { ... }` which is now deleted as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^authorize {$/,/^}$/c\authorize {\n ...\n}' file
```

Use a range to change the file.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't explain well. The `...` only indicates that there is more stuff that I want to keep.  I only want to remove `update request { ... }`